# Install the pkcs11 engine for openssl 1.1.0e

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to install the pkcs11 engine plugin for Openssl 1.1.0e on Raspbian Stretch. The usual package **libengine-pkcs11-openssl** install an engine for an earlier version of Openssl. Unsurprisingly it yields an error message about incompatible versions.

It seems it expects a library at **/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/engines-1.1/pkcs11.so**. But I can't find any Raspbian package containing such a file.

Can somebody tell me what package(s) I need to install for this ? And how it translates to the Openssl config ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Debian Stretch (not Raspberry). Unfortunatly I dont have a solution yet. It could be a bug in the Debian repository.

Debian Stretch comes with:

```
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
```

However, Debian seems to supply a library for 1.0.2:

```
# dpkg -S pkcs11.so
opensc-pkcs11:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/onepin-opensc-pkcs11.so
libengine-pkcs11-openssl:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/libpkcs11.so
opensc-pkcs11:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/onepin-opensc-pkcs11.so
libengine-pkcs11-openssl:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.2/engines/pkcs11.so
opensc-pkcs11:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
opensc-pkcs11:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

There also seems to be a bugreport for this issue, but it looks like it will not be fixed any time soon. See Debian Bug https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=846548

To resolve this issue I compiled the PKCS#11 engine myself. I downloaded it from https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11/

Please note that besides the usual compilation tools (apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake) you also need package pkg-config. Otherwise the installation fails.

Using the newly compiled driver I managed to get it working:

```
# OPENSSL_CONF=./hsm.conf openssl engine  
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(pkcs11) pkcs11 engine
```